# ClickOnce Publish does not publish updated NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, clickonce

When I publish my application (using Visual Studio), I always end up with the same (old) NuGet package version of a library, i.e. the updated package does not get published, therefore will not be installed and therefore the application crashes on startup (after being updated) as the required dependency was not found.

That's how my solutions looks like:

```
Solution\
   LibraryProject (with NLog (5.0.0-preview.1) added/updated via NuGet)
   MainAppProject (gets published)
```

Before updating the `NLog` library, it was at version `4.7.10`. That's the version the first published version of the App was shipped and installed with.

Now after I updated the NuGet package, the publish process still ships the old `4.7` version (looking at the dll file properties in the publish folder). Yet in all `bin\` and `obj\` folders I see the new dll.

Also, in the output of the publish build, I see the new version used:

```
2>-r:"C:\Users\dev\.nuget\packages\nlog\5.0.0-preview.1\lib\netstandard2.0\NLog.dll"
```

I also switched to "Produce single file", which deletes the .dll files in the publish folder, also without any success. Switching back to non-single file also results in the old version published again.

Any ideas what I'm missing or where the old file version comes from? How can I further debug this issue (can I build with more verbose logging, if so, how?)

(I've also tried the obvious things: cleaning the solution and restarting Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Cleaning the solution did not clean the `obj\Release\...\R2R` (ready to run) folder. That's where the old dll version was. Manually deleting this folder fixed the problem for me.